# DISTINCT not working on mysql SUM

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
select 
count(DISTINCT likes.user) as likes_count, //count likes
SUM(CASE comentarios.delete WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as comentarios_count from posts p //count comments (not deleted)

left join likes on likes.post = p.id
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id
group by p.id
```

to count likes and comments one post has. I'm having wrong outputs, for example I have 2 likes and 3 comments, it will show = 2 likes and 6 comments.

I tried to add DISTINCT after `SUM(` but it didn't work to. Any ideas?

---

If an user has 2 likes - 2 comments it will show:
2 likes - 4 comments

If an user has 2 likes - 4 comments it will show:
2 likes - 8 comments

If an user has 2 likes - 10 comments it will show:
2 likes - 20 comments

If an user has 4 likes - 10 comments it will show:
4 likes - 40 comments

Comment: Would you like to add sample data as text to the question?

Comment: do you mean examples? I edit it! @P.Salmon

Comment: Please describe the different tables in your query.

Comment: It's too much effort for me to reverse engineer sample data from your examples but somebody else might.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this query,not tested

```
select 
SUM(CASE comentarios.delete WHEN 0 THEN 1*likes.user ELSE 0 END)  as likes_count, //count likes
SUM(CASE comentarios.delete WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as comentarios_count from posts p //count comments (not deleted)
left join likes on likes.post = p.id
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id
group by p.id
```

Comment: How do you know which id corresponds to which SUM ?!?!